# I want to count the number of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $V_n(F)$ that contain a vector of Hamming weight $w$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Let  $V_{n}(F)$ be a vector space over the field $F=\mathbb Z_{p}$ with $\dim( V_{n}) = n$, i.e.,  $ \lvert V_{n}(\mathbb Z_{p}) \rvert  = p^{n}$. Assume $ b \in  {V_{n}}  $ and Hamming weight $b$ is $w$, i.e., $w_H(b)={w}$. If  $S \prec V $ and $ \dim(S)=k$ and $\{b\mid w_{H}(b)=w \} $. How can I count number of subspaces $S$ such that $S\cap \{b\mid w_{H}(b)=w \}\neq\varnothing$?

In other words, how can I count the number of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $V_n(F)$ that contain a vector of Hamming weight $w$?

Comment: I don't understand what the edit changed (other than replaced $b$ with $a$). As far as I can tell $a$ is some fixed vector of a known weight, and you still just want to count the number of subspaces of a given dimension that contain $a$. After all, $a$ is in that intersection, if and only if $a\in S$. Please clarify.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No, $a$ is not a fixed vector . I want to count all sub-spaces  that $\{b \ \vert\ w_{H}=w \}\cap {S}\neq \varnothing$

Comment: Ahh! Ok.${}{}{}$

Comment: I think it's clearer to simply say "I want to count the number of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $V_n(F)$ that contain a vector of Hamming weight $w$".

Comment: @GregMartin thanks a lot!